# Bibliografia sui dialetti dell'Italia meridionale

Tags: regional, resources

Da qualche tempo sto lavorando coi continua dialettali tedeschi e di recente ho deciso di estendere le mie ricerche glottologiche all'Italia, cominciando col mio dialetto (il dialetto reggiano, parlato a Reggio Nell'Emilia e dintorni). Contemporaneamente ho scoperto il *griko*, il *lucano* e il l'*arbëreshe*, che mi hanno in particolar modo colpito per via della sfera culturale di cui fanno parte.

Data la mia quasi assoluta ignoranza in materia (non conto alcuna nozione appresa tramite Wikipedia), potrebbe, qualcuno di voi, suggerirmi dei testi più o meno introduttori che trattano dei dialetti sopracitati o di uno o più dialetti meridionali che, secondo voi, sono degni di nota e, per estensione, di studio?

Comment: Come note introduttive questo articolo da Treccanionline può essere utile: http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/dialetti-meridionali_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/ - la bibliografia citata alla fine può essere utile  per ulteriori approfondimenti.

Comment: Concordo con Gio, e in particolare mi risulta che la “Grammatica storica” di Rohlfs lì citata, anche se non recente, sia molto quotata.

Comment: Su [questo sito web dell'Università di Nizza](http://www.unice.fr/lirces/langues/real/dialectes/annexes/bibliographie.htm) si può trovare una bibliografia, ma purtroppo non è aggiornata.

Comment: Io da parte mia posso farti pervenire una copia della tesi di laurea di un mio amico, la quale tratta del dialetto reatino (Rieti). Non so dirti quanto poi la lettura possa essere davvero interessante però.

Comment: Grazie a tutti per i consigli. Avevo già letto il nome Rohlfs; ora che qualcuno mi ha dato la conferma, guarderò meglio nei suoi scritti. Per quanto riguarda la tesi di laurea, mi farebbe molto piacere. Mi aiuterebbe anche a capire come è impostato un lavoro di questo genere.

Comment: La domanda è molto interessante e vorrei mettere un “bounty” per incoraggiare risposte vere e proprie, ma prima chiederei un chiarimento. Del lucano non so nulla, ma il griko è strettamente imparentato col greco, così come l'arbëreshe con l'albanese; quindi non sono in nessun senso dialetti italiani (se non per il fatto di essere parlati in Italia), e anzi neppure lingue romanze, a differenza di molti altri dialetti/lingue parlati in Italia, dal friulano al siciliano. Vorrei quindi capire meglio: sei interessato a tutte le lingue parlate in Italia del sud, [segue]

Comment: [segue] compresi dialetti di lingue straniere, o ai veri e propri “dialetti meridionali”, che è un po' ambiguo, ma di per sé farebbe pensare alle lingue nate parallelamente all'italiano standard e sue “sorelle”?

Comment: @DaG Hai ragione. Il lucano è un dialetto dell'italiano, mentre gli altri due non lo sono. Nulladimeno l'arbëreshe è un dialetto dell'Albanese e il griko, in base a ciò che ho letto, non viene considerato un dialetto, ma in ogni caso discende dal greco. Ho scritto *dialetti meridionali* e non *dialetti italiani meridionali* per cercare di raggruppare le varie lingue che vengono parlate nel nostro Meridione, appoggiandomi sul fatto che molte di queste sono, per l'appunto, dialetti di altre lingue. Il mio interesse si rivolge dunque a tutte le lingue parlate in Italia del Sud.

Comment: Ciao, potresti cercare le opere di Gerhard Rohlfs (su Wikipedia: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerhard_Rohlfs_(filologo) ) ha dedicato molto dei suoi studi ai dialetti dell'Italia meridionale.

Answer (score 2):

- **Francesco Avolio** (2009), [Lingue e dialetti d'Italia](http://www.carocci.it/index.php?option=com_carocci&task=schedalibro&Itemid=72&isbn=9788843052035)
- **Michele Loporcaro** (2017), [Profilo linguistico dei dialetti italiani](https://www.laterza.it/index.php?option=com_laterza&task=schedalibro&isbn=9788859300069)
- **Carla Marcato** (2007), [Dialetto, dialetti e italiano.](https://www.mulino.it/isbn/9788815114242)
- **Carla Marcato** (2007), [Il plurilinguismo](https://www.laterza.it/index.php?option=com_laterza&Itemid=97&task=schedalibro&isbn=9788842053224)
- **Nicola De Blasi** (2014), [Geografia e storia dell'italiano regionale](https://www.mulino.it/isbn/9788815245953)
- **Denis Ferretti** (2016), [Grammatica del dialetto reggiano](http://www.corsieroeditore.it/index.html?pg=17&id=67)
- http://www.dialettoreggiano.net/index_file/gramatica.htm
- http://enosi-griko.org/Arthra/Griko_Bibliography.html
- **Francesco Saverio Lioi** (2017), Il dialetto lucano-oppidano. Grammatica
- [Le lingue della Lucania](http://www.regione.basilicata.it/giunta/site/giunta/detail.jsp?otype=1120&id=285326&value=consiglioInforma)
- **Francesco Altimari**,‎ **Leonardo M. Savoia** (1994), I dialetti italo-albanesi. Studi linguistici e storico culturali sulle comunità arbëreshe
- http://www.arbitalia.it/
- **Gaetano Gerbino** (2009), [Grammatica della parlata arbëreshe di Piana degli Albanesi](http://www.arbitalia.it/lingua/gerbino_grammatica_piana_albanesi/gerbino_grammatica.pdf)